# Custom input text field by using field handlers

Tags: views

I'm beginner in **Drupal 7**. I've searched and wasted my time a lot but unsuccessful to find the solution.

I have to add a custom input text field by using field handlers in the views?

Kindly guide me to the right track?

Comment: How did you create this custom input text field?

Comment: I followed [this link](https://kalamuna.atlassian.net/wiki/display/KALA/Custom+Views+Field+Handler) to create field handler. I rendered node title. But now I have to render a textField below this title to get users reviews and save it into the database for the current node.
I know current node id is found by URL but my client need is to get here on the views.